# Windows Inter Process Communication (IPC) (named pipe) - slave program doesn't receive any data since a random time

Tags: visual-c++

I had a host program (A) and a slave program (B),
A sends some data (as a command) to B periodically (approximately per 0.5 sec.), while B receives the command form A, it does something corresponding.

Everything goes right in the beginning, but after a while, maybe 3 mins or 5 mins later, **at a random time, B doesn't receive new command anymore,** but A is still sending new commands.

I check the state of both A & B by writing some text log, the logs look like the following:

<< What A sent >>
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
...
Command 70
...
Command 100

<< What B received >>
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
...
Command 70 (just stop here, 71 ~ 100 is missing)

---

The core part of the Host program (A):

```
...
HANDLE host_to_slave;
DWORD host_to_slave_buffer_index;
...

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    ...
    std::string temp_string = "S/1.234567/9.876543"/";
    const char *command_str = temp_string.c_str();
    WriteFile(host_to_slave,
        command_str,
        temp_string.length(),
        &host_to_slave_buffer_index,
        NULL);
    Sleep(300); // Wait for some hardware.

    // Here write temp_string (command sent to B) to the log file.
    ...
}
...
```

---

The core part of the slave program (B):

```
...
HANDLE host_to_slave;
char host_to_slave_buffer[1024];
DWORD host_to_slave_buffer_index;
...

while(true) // Infinite checking loop
{
    ...
    ReadFile(host_to_slave,
        host_to_slave_buffer,
        sizeof(host_to_slave_buffer) - 1,
        &host_to_slave_buffer_index,
        NULL);
    host_to_slave_buffer[host_to_slave_buffer_index] = '\0';

    if (host_to_slave_buffer[0] != '\0')
    {
        ...
        // Here write host_to_slave_buffer[] (command from A) to the log file.
        ...
    }
    ...
    Sleep(10); // The minimum period of infinite checking loop.
}
```

B just check if there is any new command from A forever and does something corresponding. I just cannot figure out why it does not receive any command since a "random" time. For example, something the log of B gets stuck at Command 70, sometimes, Command 30, Command 90. But the log of A always behaves as expected - keep sending command until the latest command, is there anything to do with the Windows os?

Comment: You should check the returns of `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` and potentially call `GetLastError`

Comment: Dear Mgetz, thank you for your reply. I had tried to get the return value of ReadFile and WriteFile, they show the same result: ex. A successfully sends 1000 command, but B only successfully receive 700 commands. Regard to the  GetLastError(), the return value is always 0 at both A & B

Comment: Maybe this is another clue, after the line Sleep(300) in A, some heavy calculation is conducted (I think it's not quite heavy, the CPU loading fluctuates around 50%)